# Programming on the data.table with "env" in a function

Tags: r, function, scope, data.table, environment

I am interested in joining two data.tables in a function. However, when using the new `env` for programming on the data.table, I am unable to join the data.tables in a function because the argument I attempt to join on does not exist, i.e. I get a "argument specifying columns received non-existing columns" error. How can I programmatically feed the matching column for joining two data.tables into a function? I provide a minimal working example of a surprising failure below.

```
dt.mwe.1 <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,0,10))

mwe_function = function(dt, merge_var){
  dt.internal = 
    data.table(z = min(dt):max(dt)) %>% 
    .[ , .(mv = z) , env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
  dt.internal2 = 
    data.table(z = min(dt):max(dt)) %>% 
    .[ , .(mv = z) , env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
  dt.internal
  dt.internal[dt.internal2, on = .(mv), 
              env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
}
# fails
mwe_function(dt = dt.mwe.1, merge_var = "a")
# also fails
mwe_function(dt = dt.mwe.1, merge_var = a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing your point, but what about:

```r
mwe_function = function(dt, merge_var){
  dt.internal = 
    data.table(z = min(dt):max(dt)) %>% 
    .[ , .(mv = z) , env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
  dt.internal2 = 
    data.table(z = min(dt):max(dt)) %>% 
    .[ , .(mv = z) , env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
  dt.internal
  dt.internal[dt.internal2, on = merge_var] %>% `[`
}

mwe_function(dt = dt.mwe.1, merge_var = "a")

#         a
#     <int>
#  1:     0
#  2:     1
#  3:     2
#  4:     3
#  5:     4
#  6:     5
#  7:     6
#  8:     7
#  9:     8
# 10:     9
# 11:    10
```

From the help of  `?data.table`:

> ```
> env: List or an environment, passed to ‘substitute2’ for
>          substitution of parameters in ‘i’, ‘j’ and ‘by’ (or ‘keyby’).
>          Use ‘verbose’ to preview constructed expressions.
> ```

So I guess the `env` approach does not work on the `on` argument, which, however, accepts anyways strings as input.

---

### NSE Approach

```r
mwe_function = function(dt, merge_var){
  merge_var <- deparse(substitute(merge_var))
  dt.internal = 
    data.table(z = min(dt):max(dt)) %>% 
    .[ , .(mv = z) , env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
  dt.internal2 = 
    data.table(z = min(dt):max(dt)) %>% 
    .[ , .(mv = z) , env = list(mv = merge_var)] %>% `[`
  dt.internal
  dt.internal[dt.internal2, on = merge_var] %>% `[`
}

mwe_function(dt = dt.mwe.1, merge_var = a)

#         a
#     <int>
#  1:     0
#  2:     1
#  3:     2
#  4:     3
#  5:     4
#  6:     5
#  7:     6
#  8:     7
#  9:     8
# 10:     9
# 11:    10
```

Comment: Although I have marked this answer as correct and the trick here solved my problem, I would prefer as a matter of style not to use strings for variable names in the function argument.

Comment: I am author of env arg. It's not for on arg because it has all needed flexibility already. If you don't want to use string then just catch variable name with substitute, but designing your argument to be free of NSE, especially in such a simple use case should be considered good practice.

Comment: Thank you @jangorecki, I would have preferred an answer that used substitute to catch the variable name.

Comment: ty this resolves all my issues